# Django - How to take a value of a object in a foreignkey using a filter

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

First of all sorry for my bad english.
I have a problem to access to an specific value to show in a template. Actually I can't figure the way to do it.

I need to show information about products in a template, the problem is that the product full info is stored in 3 different models, Products, ProductStock, ProductPrice

I can access to 2 of them ProductStock and from there i access to Product. But i need the values in ProductPrice too.

This are the models

The Product Model

```
class Product(models.Model):
    # Relations
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(
        Supplier,
        verbose_name=_('supplier'),
        on_delete=CASCADE,
    )
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(
        Manufacturer,
        verbose_name=_('manufacturer'),
        on_delete=CASCADE,
    )
    family = models.ForeignKey(
        Family,
        verbose_name=_('family'),
        on_delete=CASCADE,
    )
    category = ChainedForeignKey(
        Category,
        chained_field='family',
        chained_model_field='family',
        auto_choose=True,
        verbose_name=_('category'),
    )
    subcategory = ChainedForeignKey(
        Subcategory,
        chained_field='category',
        chained_model_field='category',
        auto_choose=True,
        verbose_name=_('subcategory'),
    )
    condition = models.ForeignKey(
        ProductCondition,
        default=1,
        verbose_name=_('condition'),
        on_delete=CASCADE,
    )

    # Attributes - Mandatory
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=63,
        unique=True,
        verbose_name=_('name'),
    )
    slug = models.SlugField(
        max_length=63,
        unique=True,
        editable=False,
        verbose_name=_('slug'),
    )
    product_code = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        verbose_name=_('product code'),
        unique=True,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
...
...
```

The ProductStock Model

```
class ProductStock(models.Model):
    # Relations
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product,
        related_name='product_stock',
        verbose_name=_('product'),
        on_delete=CASCADE,
    )
    warehouse = models.ForeignKey(
        Warehouse,
        default=1,
        verbose_name=_('warehouse'),
        on_delete=CASCADE,
    )
    # Attributes - Mandatory
    quantity = models.IntegerField(
        default=0,
        verbose_name=_('quantity'),
    )
```

The ProductPrice Model

```
class ProductPrice(models.Model):
    # Relations
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product,
        verbose_name=_('product'),
        on_delete=CASCADE,
        related_name='product_price'
    )
    branch_office = models.ForeignKey(
        BranchOffice,
        default=1,
        verbose_name=_('branch office'),
        on_delete=CASCADE,
    )
    # Attributes - Mandatory
    # Costo de compra del producto neto
    net_purchase_price = models.DecimalField(
        default=0.00,
        max_digits=10,
        decimal_places=2,
        help_text=_('net purchase price (without taxs)'),
        verbose_name=_('net purchase price'),
    )
    # IVA aplicable al producto
    tax_rule = models.SmallIntegerField(
        choices=TAX_RULES,
        default=1,
        verbose_name=_('tax rule'),
    )
    # Precio de compra con IVA,
    # se asigna automáticamente al guardar el objeto
    purchase_price = models.DecimalField(
        default=0.00,
        max_digits=10,
        decimal_places=2,
        editable=False,
        verbose_name=_('purchase price'),
    )
    # Precio de venta al público
    sell_price = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=10,
        decimal_places=2,
        verbose_name=_('sell price'),
    )
    # Precio de venta neto,
    # se asigna automáticamente al guardar el objeto
    net_sell_price = models.DecimalField(
        default=0.00,
        max_digits=10,
        decimal_places=2,
        editable=False,
        verbose_name=_('net sell price'),
    )
    # IVA gravado en el producto en la compra,
    # se asigna automáticamente al guardar el objeto
    buy_product_tax = models.DecimalField(
        default=0.00,
        max_digits=7,
        decimal_places=2,
        editable=False,
        verbose_name=_('buy product tax'),
    )
    # IVA gravado en el producto en la venta,
    # se asigna automáticamente al guardar el objeto
    sell_product_tax = models.DecimalField(
        default=0.00,
        max_digits=7,
        decimal_places=2,
        editable=False,
        verbose_name=_('sell product tax'),
    )
    minimal_quantity = models.SmallIntegerField(
        default=1,
        verbose_name=_('minimal quantity'),
    )
    available = models.BooleanField(
        default=True,
    )
```

Well then i need to show in the template the list of products of a specific branch office, the stock in that branch office and the price of the product for that branch office, because i have different prices depending what branch office i going to sell.

then in the function of the list i have this and i can see the Product List and the Stock

```
def product_list(request, subcategory_id=None):
    branch_office = request.user.userprofile.branch_office
    warehouse = Warehouse.objects.get(store=branch_office)
    subcategory = None
    subcategories = Subcategory.objects.all().order_by('family', 'name')
    if "all" not in request.GET:
        products = ProductStock.objects.filter(
            product__product_price__available=True,
            warehouse=warehouse,
        )
    elif request.GET.get('all') == "yes":
        products = ProductStock.objects.filter(warehouse=warehouse)
    if subcategory_id:
        subcategory = get_object_or_404(Subcategory, id=subcategory_id)
        products = products.filter(product__subcategory=subcategory)
    if "name" in request.GET:
        name = request.GET.get('name')
        products = products.filter(product__name__icontains=name)
```

I send products to the template and I access to the name of the product using products.product.name and I show the stock using products.quantity (obviously in a for loop)

My problem is how I can show the price of the product for that specific branch_office that I get form the userprofile. And show the Price of the product in the list

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a way to access the `ProductPrice` from the `ProductStock` straight from the template. You'll probably have to do some extra work in the view:

You can use:

```
# products is a ProductStock in your case
for product in products:
    product_prices = ProductPrice.objects.filter(product=product, branch_office=branch_office)
```

or reverse relations:

```
# products is a ProductStock in your case
for product in products:
    product_prices = product.productprice_set.filter(branch_office=branch_office)
```

For easy access through the template, you can use a temporary attribute. Probably not the best practice though:

```
product.product_prices = ...
```